# Can't get row to display correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I should preface this question by saying I have absolutely no background in html/css/javascript whatsoever, so please go easy on me and sorry if I use the wrong terms or am asking a silly question/not providing enough info!

I'm trying to get an expandable table to work, and after going through several rounds of script changes by reading forum threads/tutorials (changing "next" to "nextUntil", trying nth-child and then removing it etc), it's working the way I want it to (showing the next 2 rows when a row is clicked instead of just one).

However for some inexplicable reason, the rows displayed are now shrunk to only the width of the first td. When clicked, the hidden rows are the right width.

The table as it looks like now is [here](https://www.blueoceansys.com.sg/-temporary-slug-2712e0be-b8a5-4b47-80cc-6f030332f92c?hs_preview=zMUAtLXy-4087778032).
The jsFiddle showing the rows (the current version) which seems to show correct width is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zSAdR/11/).

Had to insert code or I couldn't post this question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#report tr.show").click(function(){
         $(this).nextUntil("tr.show").toggle();
         $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
         $(this).find(".show").not(".show").fadeOut(350)
         $(this).find(".show").fadeToggle(350);
     });            
     //$("#report").jExpand();
});
```

When I remove the tr `class="show"`, the row reverts to the right width, but I don't see anything that should cause this behaviour to happen (since the previous table didn't have this problem, and the only big difference from that one is the number of rows and the javascript changes. No CSS changes were made, and no stylesheets were added.)

Any help is sincerely appreciated, I am at a loss of how to proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace small changes in your CSS:

Replace this

```
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

with this

```
.show {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: It worked!! Went about it the wrong way just now and replied in error. Thank you so much Jainam!!