# Can't get nextUntil to work properly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a mobile friendly version of the table I asked a question about yesterday ([Can't get row to display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856294/cant-get-row-to-display-correctly)).

I am not able to create a working jsFiddle with what I have, but this is the script snippet:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report2 tr.show, tr.show2").click(function(){
            $(this).nextUntil("tr.show").toggle();
            $("#report2 tr.show, tr.show2").find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });            
        //$("#report2").jExpand();
    });
</script>
```

This is the jsFiddle that is unfortunately not working because I'm likely doing something wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/L1k572m5/

The table I'm working on can be seen here: https://www.blueoceansys.com.sg/-temporary-slug-8e0df85d-5c00-46d9-be54-45045f5557d0?hs_preview=XEeYfbyT-4100439951

The problem with this code is that it hides the row of circles when the topic row is clicked (e.g. Customer Relationship Management), though it works correctly when clicking the row of circles.

I thought it was clever of me to try replacing

```
$(this).nextUntil("tr.show").toggle();
```

with

```
$("tr.show2").nextUntil("tr.show").toggle();
```

and it does seem to do what I need it to, except nextUntil doesn't seem to work now! (the rows below are all toggled as well instead of just up to the next topic row)

The version with ("tr.show2") instead of (this) can be seen here:

https://www.blueoceansys.com.sg/-temporary-slug-406e6c0c-b588-4bf7-85fd-023cb70270bd?hs_preview=RkWVdtYe-4043966449

Any help would be much appreciated!

On a side note, I would be so grateful if anyone would also know how to do an accordion effect (ie: only one set of rows can be opened at a time). If it's too complicated I will forget about attempting this at all.